# React Native - Expo export .apk crash

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, crash, expo

I'm trying to export application via **expo build:android**. After installing this .apk on device, when I try tu run application, **it crashes right after run**. 
Logcat *(this print is repeated 8-10 times)*:

```
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.diplomova_praca, PID: 2222
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expo encountered a fatal error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'p.SQLite[t]'), stack:
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: exec@671:818
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: open@671:3999
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: o@671:1317
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@671:10951
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@671:684
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@412:575
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1473
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@406:228
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1473
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@6:57
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1473
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: d@2:875
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: global code@851:3
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime: 
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at host.exp.exponent.experience.q.E(BaseExperienceActivity.java:7)
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at host.exp.exponent.experience.a.run(Unknown Source:2)
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
05-05 11:46:38.458  2222  2222 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Does anyone know, what the problem might be? App is running normally when I run it with Metro, even SQLite runs. 
I'm using **react-native-sqlite-storage** according to these instructions: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#how-to-use-android.
React Native version - 0.63.4.

Comment: Hi, did you find out the problem? I'm experiencing the exact same issue.